# Why is git saying everything is up to date when code in repository is not the same as current code?

Tags: git, github

I am new to git. Initially, I was able to git add, git commit, and git push my code into github repository. However, now I made changes to my code in visual studios and it doesn't show up in the repository when I push. All it says is that "everything is up to date". I only have one branch which is master. Here are my attempts:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `git add .` followed by a `git status` with "`nothing to commit, working tree clean`" means that there is no file with local modification to be added to the index.
As a consequence, there is nothing to commit, therefore, nothing to push.

You should first modify a file in your local repository before trying again the add/commit/push sequence.

Make sure that file is not actually ignored:

```
git check-ignore -v -- the_File_I_have_modified
```

Comment: I tried modifying a file then tried the sequence and it recognized the change.

Comment: @Zhuny So problem solved? The commit and the push worked after adding the change?